# use for-loop to compare two lists

Tags: python, for-loop

I have two list at the moment

```
a=[3768, 4893, 6007, 7131, 8246, 9373, 10485, 11610, 12722, 13845, 14960, 16085, 17198, 19262, 20388, 21494, 22614, 23727, 24850]
b=[3071, 3516, 4654, 5780, 6892, 8019, 9134, 10258, 11371, 12495, 13606, 14733, 15846, 16971, 18084, 18575, 19035, 20149, 21274, 22382]
```

Both lists have different size and all numbers in both lists are in ascending order.

I need to find the index for all elements in list b (b[i]) that is bigger than the element[v] (a[v]) in list a and smaller than the element[v+1] (a[v+1]) in list a,
for example,

```
b[i]>a[v] and b[i]<a[v+1]
```

I am not sure how I write the for loop, any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uhh... you only need 1 for loop since you don't need to loop over list `a` because you have the index `v`

Comment: You mean the element i + 1 of list a, right? Also, is it given that len(a) == len(b) + 1 or do you want some special behviour if that is not the case?

Comment: @Olivier not necessarily, per "Both lists have different size"

Comment: what is `v` in the conditional in the question? Shouldn't that just be `i` again?

Comment: @AdamSmith, my question is, are their length always off by one?

Comment: @Olivier fair question, but we're given no reason to think so and I don't think it's important to the answer.

Comment: @Olivier The lists are not necessarily off by one,  I will put v in question just not to confuse people

Comment: You aren't really clear about the form the result should take.  Please illustrate with a small example, as well as your coding attempt.  "I am not sure how I write the for loop" suggests a walk-through with a local tutor, rather than Stack Overflow -- but it's not a clear differentiation.

Comment: The result will be a list of index, the actual code is a bit messy, as all the code I've written is on how to generate list a and b

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` like this:

```
for i, (a1, a2, b1) in enumerate(zip(a, a[1:], b)):
    if b1 > a1 and b1 < a2:
        print(i)
```

Comment: I think you actually mean `if b1 > a1 and b1 < a2` according to the conditional in his question.

Comment: This is not a solution.  You can't index through the two lists in lock-step since, in the OP's terminology, `i` does not necessarily equal `v`.

Comment: @PaulCornelius disappointing, since this answered the question as originally asked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one line solution that uses list comprehension instead of for-loop to generate the list of all such indexes.

```
indexes = [i for i in range(min(len(b), len(a) - 1)) if a[i] < b[i] < a[i+1]]
```

Note that we used `min` to ignore indexes that would cause an `IndexOutOfRange` exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[3768, 4893, 6007, 7131, 8246, 9373, 10485, 11610, 12722, 13845, 14960, 16085, 17198, 19262, 20388, 21494, 22614, 23727, 24850]
b=[3071, 3516, 4654, 5780, 6892, 8019, 9134, 10258, 11371, 12495, 13606, 14733, 15846, 16971, 18084, 18575, 19035, 20149, 21274, 22382]
for v in range(len(a)-1):
    x = []
    for i in range(len(b)):
        if b[i] > a[v]:
            if b[i] < a[v+1]:
                x.append(i)
                continue
            elif x:
                print(v, x)
            break
```

Output:

```
0 [2]
1 [3]
2 [4]
3 [5]
4 [6]
5 [7]
6 [8]
7 [9]
8 [10]
9 [11]
10 [12]
11 [13]
12 [14, 15, 16]
13 [17]
14 [18]
```